# How to show $\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: px+y=1\}$ is unbounded?

Tags: real-analysis, algebra-precalculus, inequality

I need to show that the set $D=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R^2}: px+y=1\}$ is unbounded, where $p>0$

I know this means that I need to show that for all $M>0$, there exits $(x,y)\in D$ such that $\|(x,y)\|$ > M. Also, $D$ describes a line so it is obviously unbounded.

So, this is what I've tried:

Let $x=M,y=1-pM$.

Therefore, $px+y = 1$ and $(x,y)\in D$

This also means:

$\| (x,y)\| = M^2+(1-pM)^2=M^2(1+p^2)+1-2pM ,\tag{1}$

Now, I need to show that (1) is more than $M$ and this is the part I am not sure how to do.

I've tried:

$M^2(1+p^2)+1-2pM > M$ if:
$$ M^2(1+p^2)+1>M+2pM=M(1+2p) \tag{2}$$
and proceeded to try to prove that (2) is true:

$$\begin{align}  M^2(1+p^2)>M(1+2p) & \Rightarrow & M(1+p^2)+1>(1+2p) \\
& \Rightarrow & M(1+p^2)>2p\end{align}$$

How do I argue that $M(1+p^2)>2p$ is true, given $M>0,p>0$?

I also would like to know if there are other methods (especially if they are quicker) to prove that $D$ is unbounded.

Answer (score 1):

Show for instance that points $\left( n, 1-pn \right)$ are in $D$ for $n\in\mathbf{N}$ and that the sequence of points $(n, 1-pn)$ is unbounded as $n\to +\infty$ (easy, its euclidian norm is bigger than $n$).